# How to import a Python pure class declared in a third-party module in Odoo?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I have installed the module **mis_builder**, from the Odoo Community Association repository named **mis-builder**.

In that module, there is a pure Python class defined, out of Odoo standards:

```
class AccountingExpressionProcessor(object):

    ...

    def get_aml_domain_for_expr(self, expr, date_from, date_to, target_move, account_id=None):
        ...
```

The problem is that I need to create a customized module to overwrite the method `get_aml_domain_for_expr`, defined inside the class `AccountingExpressionProcessor`.

So in my module, I want to import the `AccountingExpressionProcessor` class. My question is:

Which is the best way to import that class in my Python file?

I did this:

```
import imp

aep = imp.load_source(
    'mis_builder.AccountingExpressionProcessor',
    '/my/absolute/path/to/mis-builder/mis_builder/models/aep.py'
)
```

And then tried to inherit from the imported class this way:

```
class AccountingExpressionProcessor(aep.AccountingExpressionProcessor):
```

This solution is not working. In addition to this, I do not want to specify the absolute path, since each Odoo instance has its own path.

I tried a lot of things with no result. I am using Python 2.7 since it is Odoo 10. Does anyone know a good solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it'll works for you or not but I've an example where ODOO implemented the same.

```
from odoo.addons.account_taxcloud.models.taxcloud_request import TaxCloudRequest
```

here code inherits the account_taxcloud(module) +  taxcloud_request(py file)
and then use the method:

```
class TaxCloudRequest(TaxCloudRequest):

    def set_order_items_detail(self, order):
```

Kindly check if it works for you. Also please update if you find any solution.

Comment: That was the first thing I had tried, but may be I forgot some directory in the path since now I have just tried again and it worked. Thank you very much!